# detecting tbody scrolling with backbone(marionette)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, marionette, dom-events

I have view that includes a table with a scrollable tbody

this is achieved using the standard :

```
table.mytable tbody {
  overflow: scroll;
  display: block;
}
```

in the view I've specified the following

```
tableDefinition =
  itemView: tRow
  itemViewContainer: 'tbody'
  template: myTemplate
  events:
    "all": "logIt"

  logIt: (a,b,c)->
    console.log "#{a.type} #{a.target.tagName}"

table = Marionette.CompositeView.extend tableDefinition
```

this all works great, except for the fact that the tbody scroll event never fires.  instead, all I get are mouseovers

any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use event delegation for the scroll event because it does not bubble up. You can read a bit more about it [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html). An alternative for events that do not work with delegation is to do a manual binding yourself on render like so:

```
MyView.prototype.onRender = function () {
  this.$("tbody").scroll(this.scrollHandler);
};
```

Comment: great success!  This is exactly the piece of knowledge I needed

Comment: Glad I could help. Please accept the answer if it solved you problems or let us know if there is something missing.

Answer (score 1):

I typically debug this by adding an "all" event and then just logging what the event is.

So

```
events:
  "all": "log"

log: (e) ->
  console.log e
```

And just see what gets spit out. Sometimes it's a slightly different name or what have ya.

Comment: that's legit, I'll give it a shot